# Ajax populating dropdown for c# results in undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I only get the text message Selektoni Tipin, but I dont get any values from the tables I only get undefined

AJAX script

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Dokument/Dokument",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                var s = '<option value="-1">Selektoni Tipin</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    s += '<option value="' + data[i].Id_Tipi + '">' + data[i].Emri_llojit + '</option>';
                }
                $("#tipiDropdown").html(s);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller method

```
 public ActionResult Dokument()
        {
             return View();
        }
        // GET: NgarkoDokument

         public ActionResult GetTipi(int tipiId)
        {
            Test_kristiEntities db = new Test_kristiEntities();
            return Json(db.Tipi.Select(x => new
            {
                Id_Tipi = x.Id_Tipi,
                Emri_llojit = x.Emri_llojit
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

           // return View();
        }
```

Model i built with some tables

```
public class NgarkoDokument
    {
        public Dokumenti Dokumenti { get; set; }
        public Fusha_Indeksimit FushaIndeksimit { get; set; }
        public Vendndodhja_Fizike Vendndodhja_fizike { get; set; }
        public Tipi Tipi { get; set; }

        
    }
```

And here is the html

```
<select title="Lloji i dokumentit" name="lloji" class="form-control col-md-3 box" id="tipiDropdown"> </select>
```

Comment: can you print data variable in success function so that we can see what data is being returned?

Comment: I think you should send request to `url: "/Dokument/GetTipi"` instead of  `url: "/Dokument/Dokument"` by AJAX, becuase `Dokument` returns empty view.

Comment: i updated the link but still doesnt work

Comment: Im getting this error in the debugger: GET https://localhost:44365/Dokument/GetTipi?{} 404

Comment: What's the name of your Controller?

Comment: NgarkoDokumentController

Comment: So the url should be like `/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi` and by the way, do you use `tipiId` in `GetTipi` function? If you don't use it remove it from parameters otherwise send proper `tipiId` parameter in Ajax request.

Comment: if i change the url to that i get another error in debugger ,Server Error in '/' Application.

Comment: Did you try with `url: "/NgarkoDokument/GetTipi",`? And also did you remove `tipiId` from `GetTipi`?

Comment: Yes i tried it but not it seems it does not enter at all at success function in ajax

Comment: In the controller method, does the return list have a value? If you put a `debugger` into the success of the ajax, does it hit it in Google DevTools? In DevTools, what does `data` show you?

Comment: I placed an debugger but it does not go inside of the success function, and I get this error ::44365/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi?{}:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()